# Retrieving string after second space in a cell - EXCEL

Tags: excel-formula

Hi I'm working in **excel** and I'm looking to find a way to retrieve a substring within a string after the first 2 spaces of a cell with a excel formula.

i.e.

**200 - Fee Income** would retrieve **Fee Income**

**217 - Revenue - Classroom** would retrieve **Revenue - Classroom**

**218 - Revenue - Online** would retrieve **Revenue - Online**

**218.1 - Revenue - Custom** would retrieve **Revenue - Custom**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your text is in cell `A1`, you could use:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" - ",A1)+3,999)
```

---

If this is a one-time task, you could also do this with **Text to Columns**, delimited on the spaces.

With VBA you could use the `Split` function, although the worksheet formula above will work too, if you replace `FIND` with `InStr`.

---

### More Information:

- Office Support : [**`FIND`, `FINDB` Functions**](https://support.office.com/article/find-findb-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628)
- Office Support : [**`MID`, `MIDB` Functions**](https://support.office.com/article/mid-midb-functions-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028)
- Office Support : [**Text Functions** (Reference)](https://support.office.com/article/text-functions-reference-cccd86ad-547d-4ea9-a065-7bb697c2a56e)

Answer (score 0):

In an arbitrary string, we can find the position of the **second** space character using the `SUBSTTUTE()` function:

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),2),1+FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),2)),9999)
```

[image]